# Function to erase substrings and explode string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to replace "http://" "https://" "www." and also explode the url on "/".

For example: http://www.google.com/whatever should return google.com

I was doing as much as I knew how on this function:

```
// Change site's title
function changeTitle(url) { 
    var title = url.replace("http://", ""); // 1
    title = title.replace("https://", ""); // 2
    title = title.replace("www.", ""); // 3
    document.title = title; 
}
```

But I want to do all the process on a separate function, e.g: `function cleanUrl(url)`. I tried this and variants but couldn't make it work:

```
// Clean URL
function cleanUrl(url) { 
    var title = url.replace("http://", ""); 
    title = title.replace("https://", ""); 
    title = title.replace("www.", ""); 
}

// Change site's title
function changeTitle(url) { 
    cleanUrl(url);
    document.title = title; 
}
```

How do I do it? Also I'm not exploding the url since I didn't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Clean URL
function cleanUrl(url) {
    var title = url.replace("http://", "");
    title = title.replace("https://", "");
    title = title.replace("www.", "");
    var exploded = title.split('/');
    title = exploded[0];
    return title;
}

// Change site's title
function changeTitle(url) {
    title = cleanUrl(url);
    document.title = title;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var url = 'http://www.google.com/whatever';
var domain = url.split('/')[2].replace('www.', '');
alert(domain);   // google.com
```

Comment: you have to replace('www.', ''); with this code, this would alert .google.com (note the dot)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function cleanUrl(url) { 
  var title = url.replace("http://", ""); 
  title = title.replace("https://", ""); 
  title = title.replace("www.", ""); 
  return title;
}


function changeTitle(url) { 
  title = cleanUrl(url);
  document.title = title; 
}
```

Comment: I get "undefined" as site's title.

Comment: Sorry, try it now, I found another error in the original code. It should work now. That said @Sarfraz 's answer below is awesome. I would use that...

Answer (score 1):

You should add a return statement at cleanUrl function in order to get the title:

```
// Clean URL
function cleanUrl(url) { 
    var title = url.replace("http://", ""); 
    title = title.replace("https://", ""); 
    title = title.replace("www.", ""); 
    return title;
}

// Change site's title
function changeTitle(url) { 
    var title = cleanUrl(url);
    document.title = title; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This remove all starting http or https or www (if defined) and remove url path part from URL:

```
// Clean URL
function cleanUrl(url) { 
    return url.replace(/^(http(s)?:\/\/)?(www\.)?([^\/]+)(\/.*)?$/gi,"$4");
}

console.info(cleanUrl('hTTp://google.com/whatever')); // result: google.com
console.info(cleanUrl('htTPs://google.com/whatever')); // result: google.com
console.info(cleanUrl('http://www.google.com/whatever')); // result: google.com
console.info(cleanUrl('https://www.google.com/whatever')); // result: google.com
console.info(cleanUrl('wWW.google.com/whatever')); // result: google.com
console.info(cleanUrl('google.com/whatever')); // result: google.com
console.info(cleanUrl('google.com')); // result: google.com
console.info(cleanUrl('ttt.www.google.com/whatever')); // result: ttt.www.google.com
```